# Rails 3 HABTM find by record associated model attribute

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, has-and-belongs-to-many

I think this is really basic but I'm horrible with SQL so I have no idea how to do it...

I have a standard HABTM relationship between two models, LandUse and Photo. So I have a land_uses_photos join table, and each model has the standard macro, like:

```
Photo
has_and_belongs_to_many :land_uses
```

The land use table has: ID, and Name(string).

I want to find Photos where Land Use Name = 'foo','bar',or 'baz'. How do I do that?

I looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4687004/rails-habtm-relationship-how-can-i-find-a-record-based-on-an-attribute-of-th/4687045#4687045) and tried:

```
Photo.includes(:land_uses).where('land_use.id'=>[6,7])
```

... but that gave me:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: No attribute named `id` exists for table `land_use`
```

That's bogus, here's the schema.rb for both LandUse and the join table:

```
create_table "land_uses", :force => true do |t|
  t.string   "name"
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
  t.integer  "display_order"
end

create_table "land_uses_photos", :id => false, :force => true do |t|
  t.integer "land_use_id"
  t.integer "photo_id"
end
```

So, how do I do this kind of find? And to make it only one question instead of two, how could I find with an "and" condition instead of only an "or" condition?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Photo.joins(:land_uses).where('land_uses.name' => ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'])
```

Comment: Do you know what the difference between `joins` and `includes` is?

Comment: Use `includes` when you want to eager load the association data. This is useful when you want to avoid the N+1 problem. Use `joins` everywhere else, since it generates a much simpler and faster sql.

Answer (score 1):

you gen an 'id' error since table name is: `land_uses` and not `land_use`

Comment: Oh, ok so that's the table name not the model name... still learning, but this helps, thanks!