# Find and count all Profiles with object name of HABTM relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, has-and-belongs-to-many

In my Rails 3 app I have two models, `Profile` and `Item`. Each has a HABTM relationship with the other. In my Profile model, I have a method `wish_items` that creates an Array of that same name (wish_items). If an item contains the category "wish", it is added to the `wish_items` Array for that profile.

For the purpose of this question, say I have an item named "phone" with category "wish". What I'd like to do is be able to find and count all Profiles that have "phone" in their `wish_items` Array so I can render that count in a view. My code is below.

My `Profile.rb` model:

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :items

  def wish_items
    wish_items = Array.new
    items.each do |item|
      if item.category == "wish"
        wish_items << item
      end
    end
    return wish_items
  end
end
```

My `Item.rb` model:

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :profiles
end
```

I have a join table `items_profiles` for this relationship. Here is that migration:

```
class CreateItemsProfiles < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :items_profiles, :id =>false do |t|
      t.references :item
      t.references :profile
    end
  end
...
end
```

I saw this [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4687004/rails-habtm-relationship-how-can-i-find-a-record-based-on-an-attribute-of-t) and gave the answer a try but got an error `NameError: uninitialized constant phone`. Here is the code I tried from that:

```
Profile.all(:include => :items, :conditions => ["items.name = ?", phone])
```

Specifically I put that code in the following:

```
<%= pluralize(Profile.all(:include => :items, :conditions => ["items.name = ?", phone])).count, "person") %>
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above was failing because I didn't have phone in quotations. Simple. The following worked:

```
Profile.all(:include => :items, :conditions => ["items.name =  ?", "phone"])
```

And pluralizing:

```
<%= pluralize(Profile.all(:include => :items, :conditions => ["items.name =  ?", "phone"]).count, "person") %>
```